# PostgreSQL resultSet.getLong() results in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when column type is bigint

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.1

i have a view in PostgreSQL 9.1 with a column of type bigint. This type should be mapped to `Long` in Java but actually is mapped to `BigInteger`. So

```
resultSet.getLong(columnPos)
```

results in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
resultSet.getBigInteger(columnPos)
```

or

```
resultSet.get(columnPos)
```

both with a following `toString` and parse work fine.
What would be the correct handling of this? Should i first get the `BigInteger`, call `toString` and parse the `Long`? Or Is there a better approach to tell the `ResultSet` or the `ScrollableResults` the correct Java column type?

Thank you.

Comment: new BigInteger(rs.getString("bigint_id_column"))

Answer (score 1):

The `bigint` datatype is correctly mapped to `BigInteger` since that's what it says: it is a big integer which might not fit into a Long.

You could use `resultSet.get(columnPos)` and then check the class of the returned object.

We wrote a utility class for that, so we'd do something like this:

```
public Long getLongFromResultSet( ResultSet rs, int columnPos ) {
  Object value = rs.get( columnPos );

  if( value instanceof Number) { //this should handle any numeric Java type like BigInteger, Long etc.
    return ((Number)value).longValue(); //autoboxing here
  }  

  ... //handle non-Number cases
}
```

Comment: A bigint in PostgreSQL is a signed 64 bit number, which maps directly to a long in Java. I'd say it should work

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for your answer. Your approach seems good to me, because that way you don't have to convert to a string and then to a number again.

Answer (score 0):

While inserting BigInteger value using jdbc

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("18446744073709551615"); // max unsigned 64-bit number 
statement.setObject(1, bi, Types.BIGINT);
statement.execute();
```

while reading result set : if facebok_id is of type BigInteger

```
value.setFacebook_id(BigInteger.valueOf(rs.getLong("facebook_id")));
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, in the current PostgreSQL JDBC implementation (pgjdbc) this doesn't seem to be a problem: getLong works fine on BIGINT columns. The current implementation doesn't even implement anything called getBigInteger. 
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgResultSet.java

Also, getLong seems safe on SMALLINT, INT, and BIGINT.